# A tricky situation involving compound growth rate between two different data frames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to calculate compound annual growth rate between census years (2011, 2016) and use that growth rate to extrapolate numbers for the in-between years.

### For example

```
df_2011.head()
Age      Census_Tract_001   Census_Tract_002
0        100                600    



df_2016.head()
Age      Census_Tract_001   Census_Tract_002
0        400                360
```

### Then calculate CAGR between 2011 and 2016

```
Age      Census_Tract_001   Census_Tract_002
0        .3195              -.0971
```

### Apply CAGR to each of the inbetween years

create df_2012

```
 Age      Census_Tract_001   Census_Tract_002
 0        131.95             541.74
```

create df_2013

```
 Age      Census_Tract_001   Census_Tract_002
 0        174.108             489.137
```

create df_2014

```
 Age      Census_Tract_001   Census_Tract_002
 0        229.7355           441.6418
```

create df_2015

```
 Age      Census_Tract_001   Census_Tract_002
 0        303.136           398.7584
```

### My attempt

I tired doing the following
Number of years
ny = 5

Present Turnover
pt = ?

Past turnover value
ppt = ?

m =(pt/ppt)

AGR = Annual Growth rate
agr = float((m**1/ny)-1)*100

I tired to do this for hours but if I can't I will just ref cells in excel to calculate, sadly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the CAGR directly by applying formula

```
cagr = (df2/df)**(1/5) - 1

    Age     Census_Tract_001    Census_Tract_002
0   NaN     0.319508            -0.09712
```

To find the in between `df`s, define a function

```
f = lambda c: c + c*cagr
```

And compound it by call it using function composition

```
>>> f(df)
        Age     Census_Tract_001    Census_Tract_002
0       NaN     131.950791          541.728271

>>> f(f(df))
        Age     Census_Tract_001    Census_Tract_002
0       NaN     174.110113          489.115866
```

Comment: do you have to sort the columns before you run it?  because I am getting a ton of nulls.

Comment: @OptimusPrime I don't know what your original `df` is, but just filter them to have the same columns (and in same order) :)